# How to pass params into a model callback method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, parameters

I have an 'after_update' callback method in my model:

```
after_update :reprocess_image
```

and I want to pass the params[:member] I collected from my edit form into this reprocess_image method after updating.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an experienced railer, but I think it would work if you simply use a property of your model to store this value.

something like:

```
my_class.member = 'a-member'

class MyClass
  after_update :reprocess_image

  def reprocess_image
    do_something_with_your self.member
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I ended up doing. It seems like the only way you can access those params is after you have saved them into your object instance. Also, I'd like to add that you can even exclude the 'self' part and just pass in 'member' and rails will understand.

Comment: As a side note: setting an `attr_accessor` which does not correspond to a database column on a model instance `object` and calling `object.reload`, keeps this property intact on the original `object`. This call to `reload` will only fetch the latest database attributes and does not get rid of the property defined by `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to do this at the instance level. You can use a virtual attribute:

attr_accessor :member